# How can I run two loops simultaneously - C++?

Tags: c++, loops

Like if I want to check whether a string is a palindrome or not, how can I Implement it using two simultaneous loops so that it can be done in the shortest number of lines?

Comment: Length of time and length of code are unrelated

Comment: You can spawn a new thread. Now the question is; does your task lend itself to parallelism?

Comment: Using multiple threads you can have multiple tasks executing at the same time. If you don't know about threading you'll need to do some homework but as Ed said it is important to first identify if your desired task can be run in parallel first.

Comment: What do you mean by parallel?

Comment: At the time of this writing, your question has a -7. This score is so low because it's not a very good question: as Luchian Grigore and dasblinkenlight have pointed out, running two loops simultaneously is not the best way to solve your problem. When asking questions, always try to focus on the problem rather than what you think might be the answer -- if you knew the answer, you wouldn't need to ask the question. That will lead to better and quicker answers, and higher question scores (which will also lead to better and quicker answers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is almost certainly a homework, here is an explanation of the approach with no code.

You do not need two loops, you need two *loop variables*. Start the first one at the beginning of the word, and the second one at the end, compare the characters at loop indexes, and return false if they are different. If the characters are the same, move to the next iteration by advancing the front index forward and the back index backward. Stop when the front index is equal to or greater than the back index.

Here is the syntax that lets you use two loop variables in a single loop:

```
for (int front = 0, back = s.size() ; front < back ; front++, back--) ...
```

Comment: How do i use two loop variables in a single loop?

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: this is just a threaded alternative, I don't suggest using this solution*

You can start two threads and use a `queue`.

The first thread iterates from the start and pushes elements into the queue.

The second one starts from the end and pops elements from the front of the queue (if they match).

Stop when elements don't match or when you reach the middle of the word. If elements didn't match or the queue isn't empty at the end, it's not a palindrome.

Note that this requires some serious synchronization. Don't do it like this, just parse it normally... I doubt there's any performance gain.

Comment: Worth noting: this is a good answer to the question asked, but the question asked is not about the actual problem to be solved. +1 anyway, since it is the question asked. I think dasblinkenlight's answer is more likely to help the asker though. EDIT: I like that you made it more explicit that this wasn't recommended. If I hadn't already +1'd, I would definitely now.

Comment: @DragoonWraith might be interesting to see if there's any gain for larger strings. I think there could be.